# How can I read and write from and to a JSON file?

Tags: java, json, file-io

So I tried to write some code using what I found out on different sites but nothing works. Every time I try to write in to the file it doesn't work.

Here is the code for writing and reading from and in a JSON file:

```
HashMap<Word, ArrayList<Word>> map=null;
   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("Dictionar.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        map=(HashMap) jsonObject;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dictionar dictionar=new Dictionar();
    dictionar.setDictionar(map);
```

Here is the code for writing to the file:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.putAll(dictionar);
        File f=new File("Dictionar.json");  
        f.createNewFile();  
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(f); 
    obj.writeJSONString(file);
        System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
    System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + obj);
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The  variable `dictionar` is a HashMap.

Comment: Did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java "How to parse json in Java" You might also want to use a debugger to inspect your variables.

Comment: Yes but nothing works evrething I try to write it dosen't writes in the file

Comment: You probably need to close/flush the FileWriter